# (nontrivial) isotrivial family of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, nt.number-theory, moduli-spaces, ag.algebraic-geometry

I think it should be a standard procedure to construct such things, can anyone give a reference or give a hint? Can this be done over any base scheme?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you clarify what you mean by an isotrivial family.  I take this to mean (after shrinking the base to get an actual relative elliptic curve, i.e., discarding singular fibers), the j-invariants of all the fibers coincide.  

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use quadratic twists.

**Edit**: So as not to drag things out, I hope it's okay if I just give you a standard example.  Let

$E_0: y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$

be your favorite elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., any will do).  Consider the 
elliptic curve
$E: t y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$
over the rational function field $\mathbb{Q}(t) = \mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{P}^1)$.  Spreading this out as a scheme over $\mathbb{P}^1_{/\mathbb{Q}}$, we see that there are two singular fibers, at $t = 0$ and $t = \infty$.  Discarding these we get an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ which is isotrivial -- the $j$-invariant over every fiber is $j(E_0)$ -- but nontrivial: the isomorphism classes of the fibers are in bijection with $H^1(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Q}^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}$.

It's a good bet that you'll find this example somewhere in the chapter on elliptic surfaces in Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Can it be done over any base scheme?  Unless I misunderstand, of course not, e.g. not over the spectrum of a field.

Comment: Is this right? Consider the family of elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+tx$ defined over Spec(k[t]), every fiber (except for t=0) is an elliptic curve with the same j-invariant 1728. but then how to demonstrate that this family is not a trivial family (i.e. tensor product of Spec(k[t]) and a single elliptic curve)?

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Those fibers are isomorphic over C but not over Q, right? My example seems to also work out, except that the fibers seem to be more than 2 kinds (over Q)?? Thank you!

Comment: There are infinitely many kinds of fibres! Q^x/(Q^x)^2 is an infinite group: it's a vector space over Z/2Z with basis -1 and the prime numbers.

Comment: @basic: Your example uses "quartic twists" rather than quadratic twists (for that, see Chapter 10 of Silverman's _Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves_) but it is otherwise the same (and there are still infinitely many isomorphism classes of fibers over k, if k is any number field).  So yes, that works too.

Comment: @basic: if your $y^2=x^3+tx$ were a trivial family, then it would be equal to the family y^2=x^3-x. The latter curve has all its 2-torsion, so if your family were trivial then the 2-torsion in your curve over S:=Spec(k[t][t^-1]) (considered as a global object) would be four copies of S. But the two-torsion in the t-curve isn't four copies of S, as you can easily check (you are taking a square root of -t).

Answer (score 4):

(**Edit:** added motivation for my "answer" even though it isn't exactly what was asked for. It shows the moduli space of genus 1 curves cannot be fine - see last paragraph.)

The Hopf surface is a (non-algebraic) example of a non-trivial family of isomorphic elliptic curves. Here I use "elliptic curve" to mean "smooth complex curve of genus 1", which is probably not what you mean. (In particular my curves have no distinguished base point.)

The Hopf surface $X$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus0$ by the action of $\mathbb Z$ generated by $z \mapsto 2z$. Since this action commutes with the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ there is a map $X \to \mathbb{CP}^1$. Each fibre is a copy of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ divided by the action $z\sim 2z$. So all the fibres are isomorphic elliptic curves. (If you want base points on each curve, this example doesn't work because the fibration $X \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ doesn't have a section.) On the other hand, its easy to see that $X$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$ and so you can't trivialise the fibration even topologically. Replacing $z\mapsto 2z$ by $z\mapsto \lambda z$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ non-zero, I guess you can get any genus-1 curve to appear as all fibres of a topologically non-trivial family.

Even though this is not eaxctly what you're looking for, I thought it worth giving the example anyway, because it's a very simple way to see that the moduli space of genus 1 curves cannot be fine. (Fine moduli spaces carry a universal family and all other families are pulled back from the universal family via the map to moduli space - in particular a family of isomorphic objects in such a moduli space is pulled back by the constant map and so  must be trivial. One often sees that objects cannot be parametrised by a fine moduli space by giving examples of special objects with "extra" automorphisms. The Hopf surface is an alternative to that approach in this situation.)